# Access to custom user edit form

Tags: users

I've created a path (/user/{user}/edit/ and use a custom template to user Profilform. I have a problem with restricting access. I have a "Access denied" when i want to go to my custom path

See my checkAccess function into Controller class :

```
  public function checkAccess(AccountInterface $user) {

    $currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $currentUserID = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();  
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($user == $currentUserID);
  }
```

And my routing.yml file :

```
 entity.user.edit_form:
  path: '/user/{user}/edit'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Update your profile'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_user_profil\Controller\UserEditController::content'
  requirements:
   _custom_access: '\Drupal\custom_user_profil\Controller\UserEditController::checkAccess'
```

What is the solution to allow access only if current logged has same id AS parameter {user} on the path ?

Answer (score 0):

The code chunk you posted above is really interesting so to speak:

1.

```
 $currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
 $currentUserID = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
```

You put the `currentUser` into a variable and you call the static Drupal function again to get its ID. What is the sense?

2.

```
return AccessResult::allowedIf($user == $currentUserID);
```

The `$user` object should equal to an ID? (probably int)
This doesn't really make sense in the first place.
Why don't you debug it? I mean, it keeps giving you back DENIED. Why don't you `kint` or `vardump` the two variables you are trying to compare?

3.
Letting just the user with the same id watch his user form is not a wise idea. You should also let `administrator` role and `user-id: 1` (admin user) to access it as well.